# Is $(G - v) / e$ = $(G / e) - v$?

Tags: graph-theory

Specifically, I am working with the case where $G$ is a 2-connected graph and $\{ x,y\}$ is not a cut-set of $G$, with $e = xy$. Let $x\neq v \neq y$. I want to argue that $(G - v) / e$ = $(G / e) - v$. $G /e$ is $G$ contracted along the edge $e$.

My intuition seems to think this is true, but I am skeptical about there being some weird counterexample since I have no idea how to prove this.

Any remarks are appreciated.

Comment: I'm almost certain this is true. I'd just write out carefully the definition of edge contraction and see how it interacts with vertex removal on the edge set and vertex sets of $G$.

Comment: The edge $e$ does not belong to the graph $G-v$, so the LHS is not defined.

Comment: Why is $e\notin E(G -v)$ if it is specified that $v \neq x$ and $v\neq y$ where $xy = e$? When is it not well defined?